# filterAcceptRows() is being called for all the top level items in the tree

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have taken editable tree model example for my application and try to implement proxyModel on top of it.
I have re-implemented filterAcceptRows() function, when I apply filter this function is calling for all the top level items.
Is it possible to call this function only for the items which are visible currently in a view & then when I scroll down Apply same filter for newly brought items into view ?

Because I have lots of data from DB (more than 2 million top level items and child inside them), its taking much time to filter.

Or any suggestions while handling lots of data with filtering capability (I am doing lazy population too & I want my filter to be behave [like this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46471-QTreeView-Filter)   , so when I am actually iterating through all the parent and child items it is taking lots of time).

Comment: How do you want to detect what items should be visible? TreeView is not optimized very well, because it more complex.

Comment: @SaZ I have a column number and data to be hide, but my question is completely different here.

Comment: filterAcceptRows is called by QTreeView, you don't manage it. If you want better performance - optimize your code or create your own view.

Comment: @SaZ  I have customized view in my project already, what exactly i need to do in view in order to achieve this behavior.

Comment: You need to create your own tree view, that will work how do you want. From the begining. It is very complex task and I beleive that a single developer can't do it better, then all Qt team did it for several years. I'm not talking about customizing existing `QTreeView`.

Comment: I propose you to optimize your model and your filter method. If you want to do any optimization with view it means that you have conceptual problems with your models.